# How to save Application theme name in App.config

Tags: c#

In my application user can select any theme to apply. But if he closes application and opens it again, Themes changes doesn't same. I want that these changes should be saved so if user after applying theme will open it again, changes should be saved and apply.

Should I have to save name of theme in `app.config` or is there any other way to solve this?

I need your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want a different theme for each user?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Theme" value ="YOUR_COLOR"/>
</appSettings>
```

and use it in this way in the application:

```
using System.Configuration;
string myTheme=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Theme");
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer,but i don't know how can change Metro Theme?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about an **ASP.NET** application - you should read the [How To: Apply ASP.NET Themes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yy5hxdk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) documentation MSDN.

Basically, in the `web.config` of your web application, you can define the theme to be used:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <pages theme="ThemeName" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

With this configuration, the ASP.NET web application will automatically use that theme - no manual coding necessary on your side.